# Win8/RT Using a custom (.ttf) font

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm using this code in a `Grid` inside a `Page` to make my `TextBlock` use a custom font from /fonts/pirulen rg.ttf.

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="617,49,0,0" Text="I Am the New Font" FontFamily="fonts/pirulen rg.ttf#Pirulen Rg" />
```

The font style is recognized when this Textblock is opened in the Property editor, but not so in the designer and neither when the app is running (it defaults to existing font from the system's font collection).

The build action of pirulen rg.ttf is set to 'Content'. What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set FontFamily to `/fonts/pirulen rg.ttf#Pirulen Rg`. Notice the leading '/'. Basically relative paths are relative to location of your XAML file, so unless your XAML file is in the root you should start your asset paths with '/'.

Comment: That's good to know but it won't apply in my case - both the xaml page and the fonts folder are in the root, adding the slash was in vain. I can confirm that the `.ttf` is getting copied  into the fonts folder in `Package.Current.InstalledLocation` though.

Comment: Hmm. We use custom fonts in our app and it works fine... One more thing to try: rename your font to Pirulen-Regular.ttf, maybe its the space in the file name.

Comment: That did it! Had to remove the space from both the filename and set the `FontFamily` as only #Pirulen instead of #Pirulen Rg.